# Google Sheets Stopwatch

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, timer, stopwatch

I'm trying to make a stopwatch that tracks ins and outs of staffs in Google Sheets I couldn't seem to get it to work what I would like it to do is whenever they hit IN the timer starts counting their hours then when they hit OUT the timer stops this is for when they have breaks lunch etc. this is not a normal job so I need it to work like this here is the code I have so far which only shows 00:00:01 it wouldn't continue on counting

```
var app=SpreadsheetApp;
var seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0
  
function timer() {

    seconds++;
  
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }
    app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell().setValue(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you are approaching this will use your daily quota way too fast.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

An easier solution would be to store the start time and user info on a separate spreadsheet tab and then compare that to the end time (when they press the OUT button) and the script below will convert those times to total minutes worked.

```
function timeLapse(inTime, outTime) {
      // Calculate new time
      var newTime = outTime - inTime;
      // Get datevalue in minutes
      var convertMinutes = newTime/60000;
      Logger.log(convertMinutes); 
      return convertMinutes;
    }
```